# question on real analysis limits

Tags: real-analysis

Prove or disapprove

Let f:R →R, g:R →R, be such that

$\lim_{x\to p⁡}g(x)=q $

$ \lim_{x\to q} f(x)=r$

$ \lim_{x\to p}f(g(x))=r$

Comment: (1) : Your question must be written in TeX form.

Comment: (2) : Can you please show us your progress in solving this question?

Answer (score 0):

Let $(x_n) $ be a sequence with $x_n \to p$.

Since $\lim_{x\to p⁡}g(x)=q$ we have $g(x_n) \to q.$

Let $z_n: = g(x_n)$. Hence $z_n \to q.$

From $\lim_{x\to q} f(x)=r$, it follows that $f(z_n) \to r.$

Conclusion:

$$f(g(x_n)) \to r.$$

Comment: why the downvote? ?